# Downgrade atmos audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a dolby atmos `wav` file that I would like to downsample so that I can use VLC player to play it. I just need it for audio check.

I tried this command

````
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i atmos.wav -ac 1 test.wav                                                                                                                                                          Input #0, wav, from 'atmos.wav':
  Duration: 01:57:00.93, bitrate: 147492 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 128 channels, s32 (24 bit), 147456 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[auto_aresample_0 @ 0x159f09fa0] [SWR @ 0x160008000] Input channel layout "128 channels" is invalid or unsupported.
[auto_aresample_0 @ 0x159f09fa0] [SWR @ 0x160008000] Rematrix is needed between 128 channels and ?�4?? but there is not enough information to do it
[auto_aresample_0 @ 0x159f09fa0] Failed to configure output pad on auto_aresample_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!```
````

Comment: Any 'home theatre' Dolby Atmos file is unlikely to have a true 128- channel format, It will be added into either a Dolby TrueHD or Dolby Digital Plus file, or as metadata in a Dolby MAT 2.0

Comment: I just found out that audacity can do it :) . It can downsample it. Maybe there is way to do it via ffmpeg